# Check if a letter is before or after another letter in C

Tags: c

I would like to check if the first letter of a string is before or after the letter `t` in the alphabet.

For example, the user inputs "Brad" and it would print

```
"Your name starts with a letter that comes before "t"."
```

Something of that sort.

Comment: if your input is in variable In, you can check it like this `if (In[0] < 't')`

Comment: Hint:  remember that characters are really numbers, for example capitol A, 'A' is 0x41.  With that in mind, take a look at the ASCII character table (see http://www.asciitable.com/) and see if you can't think of a way to determine that 'B' (0x42) comes before t (0x74).

Comment: But beware of the fact that there can be upper and lower cases. For that just convert everything to upper or lower before comparing

Comment: There is no guarantee letters have adjascent codes or even alphabetically ordered. It depends on your execution character set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below (add checks for null and if it the first character is t itself, etc).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* t's value in ASCII */
#define LETTER_T 116

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
      /* Use toupper or tolower functions to handle casing */
      char * str = "brad"; 
      char * result = (str[0] < LETTER_T) ? "before" : "after";
      printf("%s starts with a %c that comes %s the letter t.", str, str[0], result);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee letters have adjascent codes or even alphabetically ordered. It depends on your execution character set.

Comment: @Olaf This was meant to be a simple example, not a robust solution taking into account different character sets than ASCII (i.e. Unicode, UTF-8, etc).  The answer is even qualified by 'something like below'.

Comment: That does not even imply the solution can be completely off (as it would be for e.g. EBCDIC). Btw. using magic numbers is a no-go. Any reason you don't use the integer `'t'`?